# Cannot understand folder structure for ruby project in linux

Tags: ruby, linux

I am learning rspec and cucumber from the book - The Rspec book. This question is not about those two things. It is more about linux. My book gives me instructions which make no sense. Please help me to understand it.

Create a bin in the project root directory (sibling to lib and spec), and add a `bin/codebreaker` file. If you’re on a *nix system, enter this code in that file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.expand_path( '../../lib' , __FILE__)
require 'codebreaker'
game = Codebreaker::Game.new(STDOUT)
game.start
```

Shouldn't that be a bin/codebreaker folder ? Anyway, I made a folder bin, under project root. I also made a file bin/codebreaker.rb with the above code and continued.

If you’re on *nix, now run chmod +x bin/codebreaker so we can execute

```
it, and then run this:
$ bin/codebreaker
Welcome to Codebreaker!
Enter guess:
```

Now look at that! Who knew that this little bit of code was actually going to start to make something work?

I don't get the above output when I go to project root and execute bin/codebreaker from there. I only see this output -

```
bash: bin/codebreaker: Is a directory
```

Am I missing something ? How do I make this work ?

Comment: Have you tried `bin/codebreaker.rb`, or alternatively, following the directions to the letter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions tell you to create a file named `codebreaker`. However, you created a file named `codebreaker.rb`, not `codebreaker`. In addition to the file named `codebreaker.rb` which you weren't supposed to create, you also created a directory named `codereaker` which you also weren't supposed to create.

I don't know CodeBreaker, but the instructions you posted should work, although they are a little ugly (e.g. manually fiddling with `$LOAD_PATH` instead of simply using `require_relative`). Just follow them. Or if you *do* deviate from them as you did with naming your file `codebreaker.rb` instead of `codebreaker`, then you must of course also adapt all further instructions to that change, e.g. for example running `bin/codebreaker.rb` instead of `bin/codebreaker`.

Comment: Wow ! This is weird. I created a file called codebreaker, without any extension such as .rb and it worked. What is the meaning of this ? Why would someone want to remove the extension after using it in all ruby files ? Maybe because he wants it to look like an executable, so he removes the extension ?

Comment: @stack1 file extensions are just hints about a file's contents. Especially in the  *nix world, it's quite common to not use a file extension for text files, and for executables as you said. A file extension does not influence a file's meaning, unless the software opening it requires it.